# Linear independence of matrix minors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

This is a question about how the determinantal rank of an augmented matrix relates to linear independence.  It came up for me when I was trying to follow the proof of Bertini's Theorem in Vakil's *Foundations of Algebraic Geometry*, but I think it's just a question of linear algebra.

Suppose I have a field $k$ and an $n \times r$ matrix
$$
J
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} & \dotsm & a_{0r} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n0} & \dotsm & a_{nr}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with entries in $k$, and that $J$ has nonzero corank $d$.  Let $A = k[x_{0}, \dotsc, x_{n}]$ and consider the augmented matrix
$$
\overline{J}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{00} & \dotsm & a_{0r} & x_{0} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n0} & \dotsm & a_{nr} & x_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with entries in $A$.  The condition $\operatorname{corank} \overline{J} \geq d$ amounts to the vanishing of all $m \times m$ minors of $\overline{J}$ when $m > n - d$.  Any such minor not meeting the last column is a minor of $J$, hence will vanish because $\operatorname{corank} J = d$.  Any minor meeting the last column will be a linear combination of the $x_{i}$ whose coefficients are $(m-1) \times (m-1)$ minors of $J$, and so will also vanish unless $m = n + 1 - d$.  So the condition $\operatorname{corank} \overline{J} \geq d$ amounts to the vanishing of a family of linear polynomials $f_{1}, \dotsc, f_{s} \in A$, where $s = \binom{n}{n+1-d}$ and each $f_{i}$ is the determinant of an $(n+1-d) \times (n+1-d)$ minor of $\overline{J}$ that meets the last column.

My question is: how many of the $f_{1}, \dotsc, f_{s}$ are linearly independent elements of $A$?  Vakil's proof of Bertini's Theorem suggests that the answer is $d$ or $d+1$.  I'm not really sure how to approach the problem.  I thought about trying to use the connection between vanishing minors and linear independence of columns, but that concerns linear independence in $k^{n}$, not linear independence in $A$.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out plusplusplus? I'm stumbling on the same issue.

Comment: @DanielGratzer alas, no.  Please do let me know if you make any progress!

Comment: So while I cannot help with this particular question, someone did answer my question which was the motivation for yours (if I understood correctly). In particular, they explained the bit about getting linear conditions on the fiber in the proof of Bertini's theorem. It's now in the "linked questions" bit

Comment: @DanielGratzer you did understand correctly; many thanks for asking that question!